# Android ACTION_CHOOSER not opening camera app

Tags: android, camera, huawei-mobile-services

I'm developing an Android app where user can pick a picture from gallery or open camera to take a picture to upload it to a webview.

It works fine on every device I've been able to test, but there are some users having issues when trying to open the camera, the chooser appears but when they click on the camera the chooser disappears without opening the camera. It only happens on some Huawei devices (seen only on P30 and P30 lite)

Do you know what could be?

Thanks!

Comment: I am assuming that you are targeting API 23 or above. It would be good thought to check for granted permissions first.
you can also try behaviour on your test device by removing the permission from settings and checking the "do not ask again" dialog when permission is requested.

Comment: @Mikel   Could you please provide your log file for this? We will review and give feedback ASAP.

Comment: Hi @RajaSingla, I'm checking permissions, in fact, the app works perfectly in every device I've been able to test, instead for this huawei devices.

Comment: @shirley I don't have logs, it is happening only on some users, I have not been able to reproduce the issue locally

Comment: @Mikel Do you have the P30 or other huawei devices? You can use [Cloud Debugging of AppGallery Connect](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-clouddebug-realtimedebug) to test your app.

Comment: I've bought a huawei to try to test it. A user has sent me a video, the chooser appears but once he clicks on "camera" the chooser disappears and the camera does not open.